# Easy way to find all hashes with particular values

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a following array of hashes

```
h = [{:foo=>:bar}, {:qqq=>:ppp}, {:xxx=>123}]
```

I want to find all hashes which `Symbol` in values.

Currently I use this approach, but I don't actually like it because I have to create array for each hash and extract the first element (`hash.values[0]`).

```
h.select { |hash| hash.values[0].is_a?(Symbol) }
# => [{:foo=>:bar}, {:qqq=>:ppp}]
```

Maybe there is something more elegant to do this?

Comment: feels weird you're only relying on hashes with a single key/value pair. Why not creating a dedicated object?

Comment: what output you are looking to?

Comment: I agree with apneadiving. It's not really taking advantage of what a Hash can do, they may as well be two-element arrays. If you have the ability to change the input the way @Konstantin proposes, it would make more sense.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I knew I was trying to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use array, use hash)

```
h = { :foo=>:bar, :qqq=>:ppp, :xxx=>123 }
h.select { |k, v| v.is_a?(Symbol) }
=> { :foo=>:bar, :qqq=>:ppp }
```